# Rails を起動してもブラウザからアクセスできない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rbenv, ruby, rails をインストールして

`rails new -d mysql`

を実行後

```
rails server                       
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.2.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.1 (ruby 2.6.5-p114), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:3000
* Listening on tcp://[::1]:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

という感じで起動したのですがブラウザで http://localhost:3000 を開いても
「接続がリセットされました」
とでるだけでアクセスできません
ページの読み込み中にサーバーへの接続がリセットされました。
とあるので何かしらコネクションだけは行えてる感じもします。
(3001ポートとかだと接続タイムアウトになるのでそれとはべつのエラーのようです）

Rails は VirtualBox 上の ubuntu で起動していて
ホストの Windows 上ブラウザからポートフォワーディング経由でアクセスしていますが

`rails s` のかわりに `nc -l 3000`
をしてから http://localhost:3000 をみるときちんと通信できているので
ネットワーク的な問題ではないとおもわれます

１つ気になるのは rails コマンドが gem install rails だけでは入らず
Gemfile に 'railties' というのをかいて bundle install した結果はいったものなのと

デフォルトの sqlite の設定では bundle install が通らなかったため
-d mysql をつけてプロジェクトを生成した２点で
他は rbenv, ruby のインストールとも特別なことは何もしていないと思います

Rails どころか ruby も初めて触るレベルで
どこにログや通信内容がたまってるのか原因のしらべ方すらわからないので
どこが問題かわかる方いらっしゃったらご指摘いただきたいです

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rails s

だけじゃなく -b 0.0.0.0 というのをつけたところ

MySQLの接続エラーが出たんですが
エラー画面がでたので一応アクセスはできたみたいです…